# Strange behaviour of Factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have some test models:
User

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name {generate :name}
    last_name {generate :name}
    address {generate :string}
    country {generate :string}
    zip {generate :string}
    city {generate :string}
    phone {generate :string}
    company_name {generate :string}
    signature {generate :string}
    v_token {generate :string}
    password_digest {generate :password_digest}
    email {generate :email}
    lang 'en'
    theme 'air'
  end
end
```

Contractor

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contractor, :parent => :user, class: 'Contractor' do
    type 'Contractor'
    u_token 'contractor'
  end
end
```

Customer

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer, :parent => :user, class: 'Customer' do
    type 'Customer'
    u_token 'customer'
    contractor
  end
end
```

And CustomerE

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer_e, :parent => :user, class: 'CustomerE' do
    type 'CustomerE'
    u_token 'customer_e'
    contractor
    customer
  end
end
```

In my tests I have:

```
setup do
    @customer = FactoryGirl.create :customer
    @contractor = @customer.contractor
end
```

And everything is ok with my tests.
But if I add

```
setup do
    @customer_e = FactoryGirl.create :customer_e
    @customer = FactoryGirl.create :customer
    @contractor = @customer.contractor
end
```

Then some my tests falls. Why it can be?
I DON'T USE `@customer_e` in all cases.

**EDITED:**
Ok, my show user method:

```
  def show
    user = User.find_by_u_token(params[:u])
    if !user
      render json: {status: 'error', descr: 'INVALID_U_TOKEN'}
      return
    end

    user = find_user_for_user(user, params[:id])
    if !user
      render json: {status: 'error', descr: 'INVALID_USER_ID'}
      return
    end

    render json: {status: 'ok', user: {email: user.email,
                                       first_name: user.first_name,
                                       last_name: user.last_name,
                                       address: user.address,
                                       country: user.country,
                                       zip: user.zip,
                                       city: user.city,
                                       phone: user.phone,
                                       company_name: user.company_name,
                                       signature: user.signature,
                                       lang:user.lang}}
  end
```

And my find_user_for_user method:

```
  def find_user_for_user(user, user_id)
    users = users_for_user(user)
    users.detect {|u| u.id == user_id.to_i}
  end

  def users_for_user(user)
    users = []
    case user.type
      when 'Contractor'
        users << user
        user.contractorEs.each do |cne| users << cne end
        user.customers.each do |cs| users << cs end
        user.customerEs.each do |cse| users << cse end
      else
        users << user.contractor
        user.contractor.contractorEs.each do |cne| users << cne end
        user.contractor.customers.each do |cs| users << cs end
        user.contractor.customerEs.each do |cse| users << cse end
    end
    users
  end
```

And my test:

```
test "should show user" do
    get :show, :u => @contractor.u_token, :id => @contractor.id
    assert_response :success

    json = response.body
    data = JSON.parse(json)

    assert_equal @contractor.email, data['user']['email']
    assert_equal 2, data.length
  end
```

The problem is that the `data` is actualy `{"status"=>"error", "descr"=>"INVALID_USER_ID"}`

Comment: How do the tests fail? What error or exception do you get?

Comment: which errors are you getting?

Comment: my show user method falls, where are a lot of logic where

Comment: You still haven't provided the error message or stack trace. You say that "the data is ....", but you haven't said _what_ data you are talking about or where in the code the failure occurred.

Comment: in this line the error occurs`assert_equal @contractor.email, data['user']['email']`. this assert doesn't pass and the `data` contains `{"status"=>"error", "descr"=>"INVALID_USER_ID"}`

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've asked 21 questions over a period of nine months, so I apologize if the following seems rudimentary, but given your question and your comment, I feel it's the only answer I can give.

The canonical StackOverflow question provides some code, an expectation of or desire for a particular result and some output that differs from that result. A question is either implicitly or explicitly posed as to why the output differs from the desire or expectation.

In your case, you've provided some code, an expectation (absence of an error) and some explicit questions around that.

You have not, however, provided the output you are getting, despite being asked by two users trying to help you. The first asked "What error or exception do you get"? The second asked, "which errors are you getting"? You're answer to both was "my show user method fails, where a lot of logic where". This provided no specifics and no output.

In Ruby, when an error occurs, you typically get some error message and a stack trace, the latter providing a "trail of breadcrumbs" telling you what software you were executing through whatever series of method calls you were making. Both a source file and a line number in that source file are given for every method. In general, if you want to find out where an error occurs, you look at the code around each position in the stack. If you're trying to get help with your problem, you often need to share the code associated with each position (e.g. the code form the method you were in at that position). You've not done any of that.

As to your specific case, you've said that your code fails when you add an assignment to your setup, of the form:

```
@customer_e = FactoryGirl.create :customer_e
```

You then go on to say that:

> Then some my tests falls. Why it can be? I DON'T USE @customer_e in
>   all cases.

adding your comment that:

> my show user method falls, where are a lot of logic where

In the absence of output or code, it's not possible to provide a specific reason as to why your code "fails", but we can provide a generic answer.

*Your code fails because there is some conditional logic present which behaves differently if the additional code you included has been executed (e.g. code within your `show` method that depends on `@customer_e` being defined)*

The fact that `@customer_e` is not used in *all* cases is not relevant, because it only takes *one* use to cause an error.

Comment: I'm fear my NDA, but I've edited my post